# How to recalculate normals?

Tags: shader, unity-game-engine, shaderlab

I'm trying to write a simple shader that moves all verts with a sin wave.

```
v.vertex.y += sin(_Time.y * _Speed + v.vertex.x * _Amount * v.vertex.z) * _Distance;
```

The problem is that after moving them, the normals are wrong, thus there are no real time shadows. I've searched a lot and found that I need to recalculate the normals using fake neighbours. None of the implementations were for Unity Shaderlab, so I can't just copy and paste them, and my knowledge of shader code is pretty basic so I can't translate what I found to what I need.

Can anyone help me with what and how to recalculate normals after moving a vertex?

Answer (score 1):

The math behind normal calculation is cross product.

Take vertex A, B and C from a triangle. Then create vectors AB and AC. 
ABxAC will give you the normal of the triangle. ACxAB will give the opposite normal (ABxAC = - ACxAB).

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

If you were to move the mesh from Mesh class, there is a RecalculateNormals. But I guess that doesn't apply here as you work on the shader.

Comment: Exactly, the part I fail is creating these "fake" neighbours and then create these vectors to do the cross product.

Luckily I was able to achieve a fair enough effect and ultra performant on mobile. What I did is to discard shadows altogether and created a simple texture. Now when the mesh moves the texture follows and now you can see it moving. It looks PRETTY GOOD and I don't have to deal with shadows (Since I'm targeting for mobile)

Comment: The fake neighbours, I assume are the two vectors. When you get a triangle, it is made of three points, the vertices. It does not matter which you choose, it only matters that one vertex is the starting vertex of both vectors.

Answer (score 0):

The **normal vector of a surface is related to its derivative**. In the case of a sinus wave its derivative is just cosine wave **cos()**. Both can be computed efficiently in a single operation called **[sincos()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509652%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)**.

Perfect introduction exercise :) plot both and observe the [relationship](https://www.intmath.com/differentiation-transcendental/differentiation-trigonometric-functions-interactive-applet.php).

The previous answer by Everts works when you have access to neighbouring vertices, which you usually don't in shaders (but that would be fine on the CPU).

Answer (score -1):

Having not done this myself, I did a little googly and found [this shader](https://gist.github.com/AdrianaVecc/20ae99182d89848086e95cbb6ed523e2), used to invert the normals. It does this by tweaking the vertex information:

```
    void vert(inout appdata_full v) {
        v.normal.xyz = v.normal * -1;
    }
```

You should be able to tweak your shader to recompute the normal direction based off the other alterations and update it in a similar manner.

Comment: Thank you for trying! But sadly that's the part I don't know how to achieve :(

Comment: @Al3x I don't know what math you'd use either.